# Call for global variable in JS block of Selenium Webdriver test (Python)

Tags: selenium, variables, testing, webdriver

I have a string of numbers set by user. Defined in the beginning of the Webdriver test:

`numbers = input("prompt")`

Then I need to enter value of this variable by JS code like this:

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value=***")`

Where instead of *** I need the value of "numbers" variable. How should I properly insert it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do.

```
numbers = input("prompt")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value={}".format(numbers))
```

The documentation link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

And a snip-it from the docs:

The field_name itself begins with an arg_name that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, … in sequence, they can all be omitted (not just some) and the numbers 0, 1, 2, … will be automatically inserted in that order. Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string. The arg_name can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form '.name' selects the named attribute using getattr(), while an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using **getitem**().

Changed in version 3.1: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted for str.format(), so '{} {}'.format(a, b) is equivalent to '{0} {1}'.format(a, b).

**OR**

```
numbers = input("prompt")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value=%s" % numbers)
```

See examples of both here:
https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

If your python variable's value is simple string without single quotes or special characters, you can simply use:

```py
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value='" +
    python_variable + "'");
```

If it has quote marks in it, or special characters that need escaping, or if it's not a string at all, you need to obtain JavaScript string representation of your Python variable's value. `json.dumps` will handle all the necessary formatting and escaping for you, appropriate to the type of your variable:

```py
from json import dumps

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value=" +
    dumps(python_variable))
```